# doubleclick on filename OPEN DEFAULT EDITOR in PowerShell ISE editor

Tags: powershell, file-io, openfiledialog

```
$fromDir = "C:\temp\STA\"
$controlFileArray = Get-ChildItem $fromDir\*.SSISDeploymentManifest | % { ($_.basename)}
echo $controlFilearray
```

From above script, I am taking file name in one variable,  how to double click this filename using power shell so that it will open in desired editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file is `c:\temp\t.txt try` :

```
$a = "c:\temp\t.txt"
& $a
```

Comment: it won't work when I put it in above code and end it as & $controlFilearray

Comment: What is the value of $controlFilearray ?

Comment: #this is working : your solution is cutting edge solution thank you very much JPBlanc..                                                    $fromDir = "C:\temp\STA\"
$controlFileArray = Get-ChildItem $fromDir\*.SSISDeploymentManifest | % { ($_.basename)}
echo $a = $controlFileArray".SSISDeploymentManifest" 
& $a

Comment: Start-Process PackageName.SSISManifest -verb open   this is also getting worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Invoke-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113345) to perform the default action on a file:

```powershell
$controlFileArray | Invoke-Item
```